# Are there still Legacy dialog boxes in Word 2016

Tags: microsoft-word-2016

I found most of the old style dialog boxes inside Word 2013 for Save, Open, Print, Spelling, ect, and open most them with macros like "Dialogs(wdDialogFilePrint).Show"
Does Word 2016 still have them?

I don't have Word 2016. There are a few questions I want answered before I do.

Comment: What happened when you tried to use them?

Comment: I don't have Word 2016. I'm asking before I consider upgrading.

Comment: Microsoft generally has good VBA backwards compatibility. You should probably read up on VBA changes going from whatever version you're on now to 2016.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using MS Word 2016 (16.0.8229.2073 to be exact).

`Dialogs(wdDialogFile___).Show`, where ___ is: "Open", "Print", "Save", or "SaveAs" **all work** in Word 2016.

- They all open the expected dialog box without error.

This likely suggests that (as music2myear stated in the [comments](https://superuser.com/users/74026/music2myear)) Office 2016 does have VBA backwards compatibility.

- This backwards compatibility is corroborated [here](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/10/01/microsoft_office_2016_for_developers_vba_lives_on_new_javascript_apis_coming_for_mobile/).

---

You can also see [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/mt715497(v=office.16).aspx) for a list of major changes between Word 2013 and Word 2016 and [here](https://dev.office.com/blogs/VBA-improvements-in-Office-2016) for a list of "improvements" made to VBA between versions (this mostly affects Mac users).